# Cygnus installation via RPM: Problem with repository

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

We are trying to install Cygnus via RPM for the past few days. However, we notice that the public repository is not available.

Here is the error:

```
wget -P /etc/yum.repos.d/ https://nexus.lab.fiware.org/repository/raw/public/repositories/el/7/x86_64/fiware-release.repo

--2020-10-29 11:40:54--  https://nexus.lab.fiware.org/repository/raw/public/repositories/el/7/x86_64/fiware-release.repo
Resolving nexus.lab.fiware.org (nexus.lab.fiware.org)... 109.234.71.209
Connecting to nexus.lab.fiware.org (nexus.lab.fiware.org)|109.234.71.209|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 public/repositories/el/7/x86_64/fiware-release.repo
2020-10-29 11:40:54 ERROR 404: public/repositories/el/7/x86_64/fiware-release.repo
```

Can you please suggest, how can we proceed further?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the repo which is solved now.